# How to access file from android device with ionic

Tags: android, ionic3

I'm trying to access a video from a tablet (android in this case) in ionic with this code:

```
<video preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" loop webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
  <source src="/storage/Movies/video_tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I've been searching around but I didn't found anything usefull.

First I thought that ionic needed some permissions

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

But still not working, any ideas?

EDIT: The video is located in storage/Movies/video_tutorial.mp4

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

please Add video file in assets folder or make video folder in assets folder and try like this

```
<video preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" loop webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
<source src="assets/video_tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that when I compile the app it crash because the video is so big, that's why I'm trying to put it out of the app

Comment: have u try with plugin.this is link - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/video-player/

Comment: I'haven't tried this plugin yet but I think the problem will be the same, because you still have to put the video out of the app so it does not crash :S